# Careers from the mobile feed lead to pointless home page

Tags: bug, android-app

Using the Android app, if I select a job from the feed, what I get is a vanilla stackoverflow.com home page, logged out even. What I don't get is anything remotely related to the job listing. I'm sure your paying advertisers would prefer something more effective.

[image: Image of feed with job]

Comment: Well, the android app is meant for questions and answers only (reading and posting), with very basic features only. No careers, no jobs, no chat, not even revisions list of a post.

Comment: Oh? Why, then, does it show me job offerings amongst the interesting questions in the feed? If it's not supposed to do jobs, it should, well, _not do jobs_.

Comment: As far as I remember from the few times I've clicked them, those links opened pages in a browser. This might have changed/broken since then. I'm not saying this isn't a bug, or that the links shouldn't be fixed, of course they are, just saying that the paying advertisers should not rely on the app users.